# I am having trouble with the rotate() in collections

Tags: python, list, collections, rotation, deque

i keep on getting an error when i try to shift items in a list using rotate() from collections and deque. I have used collections and deque, in order to shift each element by 1 or n.

```
from collections import deque
array= deque["a","b","c","d","e"]
array.rotate(1)
print(array)
```

when executed i get the following error

```
    array= deque["a","b","c","d","e"]
    TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Wrap those square brackets with parens: `deque(["a","b","c","d","e"])`

Comment: You need some `()` like: `deque([...])`

Comment: thanks that worked, but is there a way to get rid of the 'deque' at the start of 'deque(....)'

Answer (score 1):

`deque` is a the name of a class:

```
>>> deque
<class 'collections.deque'>
```

Therefore, `deque["a","b","c","d","e"]` is not syntactically correct. You can create a new `deque` object by instantiating it: `deque(["a","b","c","d","e"])`

This object has a `rotate` method that you can call:

```
>>> array.rotate(1)
>>> print(array)
deque(['e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

If you need to have a list object, you can do this: `list(array)`